How can I limit a flow to a certain frequency window?
I have a wrapped an external optimization library in a callbackFlow in my quarkus-kotlin backend. Now I want to push updates to my frontend, but since updates from this library arrive quite frequently (at least during the first processing steps), it makes sense to limit the update frequency to save bandwidth.
I would like to send an update whenever a better solution to the optimization problem becomes available, but not more than once every sec (let's take 5 for this example) seconds.
I know about debounce, but the documentation on that clearly states, that the resulting flow only emits a value if there hasn't been an update for the duration of a specified timeout, so it's not really the behavior I want to achieve.
My current approach is to use conflate followed by onEach with a delay like this:
callbackFlow {
    // ...
}
    .conflate()
    .onEach {
        delay(5000)
    }

Is there a better or more idiomatic way to achieve this?

Instead of conflate and onEach you could use this:
.sample(5.seconds)

From the documentation:

Returns a flow that emits only the latest value emitted by the original flow during the given sampling period.


I'm not sure if this applies, by when you emit the same value a lot, then using distinctUntilChanged might also be an option.

That is a really nice solution, thank you! Still, it does come with a bit of a drawback: Note that the latest element is not emitted if it does not fit into the sampling window. The last element of the flow is the best solution found (within a given timeframe) for the problem, so I don't want to drop that... I could think of working around this to add a delay before emitting the last item, but that's also kind of ugly. Is there a way around this?

Regarding distinctUntilChanged: This is handled by the optimization library itself. It is invoking a callback whenever a better solution than the previous best solution has been found and a separate callback containing the last best solution when solving has finished.

Then the question seems to be a duplicate of Sample Flow with last item.

While I think the custom operator provided as an answer to this question solves my problem, I don't necessarily think my question is a duplicate... But I'm also not that deep into SO meta. My point would be that without knowing sample exists, it would be quite hard to find the referenced question. So this question here might have some value when it comes to finding the sample function. But since it's technically the same answer, I also get the point about this being a duplicate. Any thoughts?

Don't worry, although duplicate questions are closed, different from other closed questions they will never be deleted. The reason for that is what you already mentioned: People may have difficulties finding the original question (and the answer they seek), so the duplicate remains there, making the original easier to find. But it wouldn't be helpful to also duplicate the answers. That's why the duplicate is closed to prevent additional answers. I probably shouldn't have answered in the first place, but I just found the other answer myself after your comment to my answer. :)

No harm done, question (and answer) can stay as they are now.
